# Bootstrap.min и Bootstrap отличия

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Не известно по каким причинам, bootstrap.css дает совершенно другой результат, в отличии от bootstrap.min.css.

Касается это в первую очередь разметки, цвета nav бар.

При использовании bootstrap.min.css - он черного цвета и с его разметкой все хорошо, но разметка оставшейся части страницы - кривая.

При использовании bootstrap.css - nav бар совершенно другого цвета, но 
нормальная разметка страницы.

С чем это связано и как это вообще лечится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootstrap.min.css - это сжатый (отсутствие пробелов и переносов строк) файл bootstrap.css

Возможные причины несоответствия:

- возможно вы используете разные версии этих файлов
- возможно вы используете файл с "вшитой" кем-то темой, изменением стилей и цветов.

Как бороться. Используйте полную версию и минифицируйте её самостоятельно с помощью различных библиотек типа webpack и др.

Comment: Файлы используются с официального дистрибутива.
Следовательно файлы одной версии и вшитых тем там нет.
Однако отличается абсолютно все, начиная от стилей кнопок, заканчивая разметкой.

Comment: Тогда нужны примеры

Comment: Видимо проблема не в самом bootstrap, а в django. Почему-то из папки static/css стили импортируются с проблемами. Из папки с другим названием - такой проблемы нет